# Дублирование папки Application Data

Tags: клонирование

открываю папку Application Data, открывается прежняя папка и так многократно и последняя Application Data вообще не открывается? Windows 10

Comment: Ошибка файловой системы. `chkdsk /f`

Comment: Какую именно Application Data вы пытаетесь открыть? Если c:\ProgramData\Application Data - то это нормально.

Comment: *Если c:\ProgramData\Application Data - то это нормально.* Что тут нормального-то? в нормальном состоянии туда доступа вообще быть не должно.

Comment: Весь диск С заполнен

Comment: Емкость диска С - 60 Гб, а размер папки "Application Data" из "C:\Program Data"  - 145Гб